# How to get a multidimensional array after submitting my form from javascript into PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax, post

One php file with php and javascript inside. I have a multidimensional array defined in the javascript part. I can see the proper output of "key" and "value" in the console but I do no get the array into php after submitting my form.
What I am doing wrong?

```
<?php
echo "Postcmd: ".$_POST["postcmd"];
print_r($_POST["postcmd"]);
?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var postcmd =[];
var key;
function formsubmitplus(ele) {
    postcmd.push({"key": ele.id, "value": ele.value});
    for (key in postcmd) {
      if (postcmd.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(postcmd[key])
      } 
    }

    request = $.ajax({
        url: "/index.php",
        type: "post",
        data: postcmd
    });

} 
</script>
```

---

Not even this simple and often found script example works for me - what else might be the issue? Are there other (basic) things to know about js->PHP?

```
    <?php
// index.php
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Pass JS array to PHP.</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var arrayfromjs = "123";
$.ajax({ 
       type: "POST", 
       url: "index.php", 
       data: { testArray : arrayfromjs}, 
       success: function() { 
              alert("Success"); 
        } 
}); 
</script>

</head>
<body>

<?php
echo "<br>Pass JS array to PHP.<br>";
$myArray = $_POST['testArray'];
print_r($myArray);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use FormData always, you will love it https://stackoverflow.com/a/5976031/4414952

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ad the end I found a solution without jquery which works for me the best.
It is "playing" with HIDDEN form fields.
Maybe someone finds it helpful:

```
function submitform() {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(postcmd).forEach(function(val, idx, array) {
    var outarrayoutput = val + ' ==== ' + postcmd[val];
    console.log(outarrayoutput);
    var newHidInp = document.createElement('input');
    newHidInp.type  = 'hidden';
    newHidInp.name  = 'outArray[]';
    newHidInp.value = outarrayoutput;
    maintable.appendChild(newHidInp);
}); 
    document.maintable.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the jQuery documentation,

> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

Thus, your `data` field must contain an object (such as `{foo: bar, foo_again: bar_again}`; in PHP, this would read as `$_POST['foo'] == "bar"`). However, your code submits an array with one element: the object specified. In addition, PHP does not magically turn your JS array/object into a PHP array. You have to parse the string passed into PHP and turn it into the array you need.

If you print `$_POST`, you can see what exactly is being passed into your PHP. That might help you see what is happening.

Comment: Using my original script the console output is: {key: "4@@@expensetype", value: "fuel"}. 
However $_POST("postcmd") stays empty after submitting the FORM. I was hoping to get an array here. 
And the output of $_POST  delivers the whole table transferred by the FORM. But the intention of using javascript is to reduce the later in PHP/SQL to be written table-fields to only the changed table-fields. 
The array built in javascript "key=ele.id:value=ele.value" comes from onchange elements at the INPUT boxes of the FORM.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the following structure using the `push` method:

```
[
  {
     "key":"first_name",
     "value": "Bob"
  }
]
```

Using your code, all you need to do is index the `postcmd` variable to the object. You also had some indexing issues with your loop. The `key` variable would just be index `0`. So you would need to set it to `postcmd[key]` to check for the key named `"key"`.

```js
function formsubmitplus(ele) {
    postcmd.push({"key": ele.id, "value": ele.value});
     for (key in postcmd) {
      if (postcmd[key].hasOwnProperty("key")) {
        console.log(postcmd[key].key)
      } 
    }

    request = $.ajax({
        url: "/index.php",
        type: "post",
        data: postcmd[0]
    });

}
```

Using the above snippet, jQuery will then parse the data into the correct key value pairs. Without specifying the index, the data would be posted as `undefined=Bob`

On the PHP side you should be able to grab those values as such:

```php
<?php

echo $_POST['key'].PHP_EOL;
echo $_POST['value'];

?>
```

---

#### Alternative Method - JSON Submission

You could make the following modification to post the data as JSON:

```js
function formsubmitplus(ele) {
    for (key in postcmd) {
      if (postcmd[key].hasOwnProperty("key")) {
        console.log(postcmd[key].key)
      } 
    }

    request = $.ajax({
        url: "/index.php",
        type: "post",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(postcmd)
    });

}
```

Then on the PHP side you can grab the POST body using the following:

```php
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    $json_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    print_r($json_data);
?>
```

If you would rather work with a PHP Object vs an Associative array. Just change `true` to `false`.

Comment: In this case the key is also variable - depending on the line number (before the @@@) of a huge table. So no hardcoded echo $_POST['key'] can be used.
The console delivers: {key: "1@@@expensetype", value: "entertainment"}  or {key: "2@@@invoicecurrency", value: "US$"} .
The so achieved array (stored in postcmd) will be "exploded" later in PHP for further processing. But how to get this js-array from javascript to PHP?